# Jar file not finding image but in Idea does

Tags: java, jar, image-loading

I'm trying to load an image in Java using Jaylib, it works in Intellij but not does as a Jar.

Method for Resource Locations:

```java
@Nullable
    public String getPath() {
        try {
            return Path.of(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(this.location).toURI()).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("No object found at location!");
            LOGGER.debug(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I tried using `getClass().getResource`, `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` and using a fat jar instead of a shadow jar.

Edit: I debugged it and this is the log:

```
[jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:156), jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:142), java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:208), com.github.command17.mariomaker17.resource.ResourceLocation.getPath(ResourceLocation.java:26), com.github.command17.mariomaker17.resource.Textures.loadTextures(Textures.java:9), com.github.command17.mariomaker17.Main.main(Main.java:42)]
```

Comment: It is generally bad idea to convert a resource location into a file path. Depending on the OS, file system and file location it can or cannot work. For example it can fail, if the path to the JAR contains the character "!". The better way is to read the resource directly as a stream.

Comment: @30thh I can't read them as streams since jaylib (raylib) needs the path to the image

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has a different way to decide, which directories must be a part of the classpath. It is very possible, the directory with a image is tagged as a resource directory in the project setting, but not in the `pom.xml` Finally the file is not exported to the JAR at all.

You need to ensure, you specify the resource directory like this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
</build>
```

Comment: I don't have a a pom.xml file. Only gradle kt and manifest.mf

Comment: And I looked into the jar and found the resources